# How to take a input value inserted by a JQuery to the same jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I am developing variant section in OpenCart using JQuery. I need to store a value to the inputs and take that input values to the another Ajax call.

I'm facing undefined error, when I take the value from the input.

Here is the HTML code:

```
{% if product_type == '1' %}
    <div class="product_variant color">
        <h3>Available Options</h3>
        {% for variant in variants %}
            <div class="">
                <label>{{variant.variant_name}}</label>
                    {% set i = 1 %}
                    <div class="radios">
                      {% for variant_value in variant.variant_values %}
                        <input type="radio" name="rGroup{{variant.variant_name}}" value="{{variant_value.variant_value_id}}" id="r{{variant_value.variant_value_id}}" />
                        <label class="radio" for="r{{variant_value.variant_value_id}}" {% if variant.variant_name == 'Color' %} style="background:{{variant_value.code}}" {% endif %}
                        {% if variant.variant_name != 'Color' %} style="background:#fff; text-align:center; padding-top:5px;" {% endif %} value="{{variant.variant_id}}_{{variant_value.variant_value_id}}">{% if variant.variant_name != 'Color' %} {{variant_value.variant_value}}{% endif %}</label> 
                        {% if i == 1 %}
                            <input type="hidden" class="variant_input_{{variant.variant_id}}" name="variant_name[]" value="" />
                        {% endif %}
                        {% set i = i + 1 %}
                      {% endfor %}
                    </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

JQuery code:

```
$('.radio').on('click', function() {
    var variant_array = $(this).attr('value').split("_");
    $('.variant_input_'+ variant_array[0]).val(variant_array[1]);
    var data = $('input[name="variant_name"]').val();
    alert(data);
});
```

Please anyone help me on this. Or suggest better method to proceed this task.

Input is an array

Comment: `.radio` is the `<label>`, not the `<input>`. It doesn't have a `value` attribute, so what do you expect `$(this).attr('value')` to be?

Comment: You have no input with `name="variant_name"`. You have an input with `name="variant_name[]"`, that's not the same thing. It's being generated in a loop, you need a more specific selector to get the one related to the input that was clicked.

Comment: You should put the click handler on the radio button, not the label. Clicking on a label automatically clicks on the corresponding button.

Comment: Through the attrib value of the label, I take the data by on click. And that value is stored in a input array as well. But I can't take the data inserted  from the input array. I need to take the values of that input array and pass it to an future AJAX call, through that I can process the variant data to the front end

Comment: Can you please answer this question? It is bit confusing me.

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: This one  var data = $('input[name="variant_name"]').val();
    alert(data);

Comment: I have created swatch using the labels not the radio inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no input named `variant_name`, the name is `variant_name[]`. You can't ignore the `[]` in the name.

You also need to select the one that's in the same DIV as the label that you're clicking on.

```
$('.radio').on('click', function() {
    var variant_array = $(this).attr('value').split("_");
    $('.variant_input_'+ variant_array[0]).val(variant_array[1]);
    var data = $(this).closest("div").find('input[name="variant_name[]"]').val();
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: It looks I can take the data from nearest input. In my case, how can I pass all data which is stored in that array to an AJAX call. Will it work for me?

Comment: `someArray.push(data)` then make the AJAX call using the array.

Comment: Here there is no order, just pushing all the clicked values.

Comment: You click a bunch of values, pushing them onto the array when you do this. Then you click on a submit button, and it sends the array in the AJAX call.